# Panorama Image in PyScript

Tags: python, panoramas, pyscript

I want to do a Panorama Image on a Html Side I already have a Python script running that makes a Panorama img realistic but now I am struggling to implement it on the html side. I hope somebody can give me a solution for that

I have different lib in use as PyQt5 and sys but even when I implement this with py-env it does not work at all it's always in a loading state. I think the reason for that is I use a ribbon and it don't come to a certain finish. All the testing was made with PyCharm on a MacOS Maybe somebody can help me by this problem if somebody wants the code sample I can send it over.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your attempts; read that link carefully, we don't need the full code, but an example based on it that is *both* minimal (as short as possible) **and** reproducible (we still need to be able to see or even run it).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.